# Filling PLA Programming Table

Tags: digital-logic

I am studying Programmable logic array.I understood that it is a type of fixed architecture logic device with programmable and gates followed by programmable or gates.For example given logic table i find outputs(Y1,Y2) functions using K maps then i implement them. I mean something like this:

[image]

whatever i just wanted to show what i studied.
The question is

this question confused me.
[image]

I got the k map part.but how do i fill input and output tables? what are C T C?

Comment: Here you go: http://studytronics.weebly.com/programmable-logic-devices.html C and T are explained too.

Comment: I read this  a T (true) specifies that the other input of the corresponding XOR gate can be connected to 0, and a C (complement) specifies a connection to 1.       but still couldnt understand..

Comment: Well, that's a really comprehensive article, and no answer here could compete with it, unless you have a very specific question about it.

Comment: One more reference for you - Fundementals of Logic Design by Charles Roth

Comment: Reminder not to give out _answers_ to the question in the _comment_ section, even if you can't bother to type a long answer.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this post has gone unanswered for a long period of time as I was just recently looking for an answer to this question. I figured it out and would like to explain it in as simple of terms as I possibly can. Let's start by answering your question "how do I fill in the input table".

To explain this, I will be using these Boolean functions
[image]

and this example table:

[image]

The inputs for this table are simply indicating which variables in the product term (the product terms are the 4 expressions in the left-most column: AB', AC, BC, A'BC') are present as well as which of these variables are inverse or not inverse. For example, the product term AC has the input 1 - 1 meaning A and C are present in the product term and are both non-inverses or not prime.

The outputs are what I had trouble understanding at first. To understand these, we need to know how our PLA works. A PLA is used to represent or calculate a set of Boolean functions, in our case the two provided above (F1 and F2). A PLA first uses an array of AND gates and then OR gates to yield Boolean functions. Take a look at the diagram of our Boolean functions below:
[image]

Let's figure out how we get the outputs "1 -" for the product term AB'. The T output is always going to be the XOR of 0 and our Boolean function, meaning the input of the XOR function is not going to be changed and will yield the same output as the input:[image]

Also see the XOR truth table to make sense of why this is:

[image]

The C output is when we XOR 1 and the output of our OR gate. In the given example, we would do this on (AC + BC) in order to yield our F2 Boolean function: (AC + BC)'. If the product term in our table does not go to a T or C XOR gate, we would simply write a "-" for the output value.

Here is a clearer visual of the diagram illustrating how we obtain these output values for our given example:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer. If there is anything wrong, please let me know.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry Mohammadsh, but this answer is inadequate. There are several problems.  The equations have no explanation. The diagrams are not entirely clear, some of the symbols are badly drawn and therefore ambiguous. I suggest that you look at the other answer to this question to get some ideas on how to do it. If you care to improve it we would be happy to look at it again, particularly if you can show it is significantly different from the other one.